# 'NoneType' object is not callable on calling model.fit_generator()

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

```
def data_generator(descriptions, photos, wordtoix, max_length, num_photos_per_batch):
    X1, X2, y = list(), list(), list()
    n=0
    # loop for ever over images
    while 1:
        for key, desc_list in descriptions.items():
            n+=1
            # retrieve the photo feature
            photo = photos[key]
            for desc in desc_list:
                # encode the sequence
                seq = [wordtoix[word] for word in desc.split(' ') if word in wordtoix]
                # split one sequence into multiple X, y pairs
                for i in range(1, len(seq)):
                    # split into input and output pair
                    in_seq, out_seq = seq[:i], seq[i]
                    # pad input sequence
                    in_seq = pad_sequences([in_seq], maxlen=max_length)[0]
                    # encode output sequence
                    out_seq = to_categorical([out_seq], num_classes=vocaab_size)[0]
                    # store
                    X1.append(photo)
                    X2.append(in_seq)
                    y.append(out_seq)
            # yield the batch data
            if n==num_photos_per_batch:
                yield [[array(X1), array(X2)], array(y)]
                X1, X2, y = list(), list(), list()
                n=0


for i in range(epochs):
    generator = data_generator(mapping, train_features, word2ix, max_length, 3)
    #print(generator)
    model.fit_generator(generator,epochs=1,steps_per_epoch=steps,verbose=1,callbacks=None)
    model.save('./model_weights/model_' + str(i) + '.h5')
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 2     generator = data_generator(mapping, train_features, word2ix, max_length, 3)
> 3     #print(generator)
> ----> 4     model.fit_generator(generator,epochs=1,steps_per_epoch=steps,verbose=1,callbacks=None)
> 5     model.save('./model_weights/model_' + str(i) + '.h5')
>
> 5 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py
> in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
> 805       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
> 806       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
> --> 807       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
> 808     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
> 809       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: You'll need to share more info. E.g. the function `data_generator`

Comment: data generator function is shared any idea how to resolve this?